# Local variable value inside measure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, scope

I have a View with nested items, implementing list-like block displaying received props array and I want to get height of this block from sum of height of all of its children. So my component looks like this:

```
class MultiColumnBox extends Component {
  state = {
    calculatedMaxHeight: null,
  };

  measureBlock = () => {
    let totalHeight = 0;

    //this.props.data is array
    this.props.data.forEach((item, index) => {
      this['checkbox_${index}'].measure((x , y, width, height) => {
        console.log(height)
        totalHeight += height;
      })
      if (index === (this.props.data.length - 1)) {
        this.setState({
          calculatedMaxHeight: totalHeight
        })
      }
    })
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View
        onLayout={() => this.measureBlock()}
      >
        {this.props.data.map((item, index) => (
          <View ref={node => this[`checkbox_${index}`] = node}>
            // some content....
          </View>
        )}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

But if there will be for example 5 blocks of height 40dp, it will console log 40 five times and set state.calculatedMaxHeight to 0. But if I move `if (index === (this.props.data.length - 1))` condition inside measure function, it will work okay and set state.calculatedMaxHeight to 200. Why is it works like that? Regardless of nesting inside measure function I work with the same `index` variable and increase same `totalHeight` varable, defined once outside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that setState function is called before the callback function inside measure invoked for first node.

**console.log(height)**  would be printing the 40 for 5 times, But the calculatedMaxHeightt is set to 0 before first print of height value.

Answer (score 0):

setState forces the component to re-render... It is not good practice to call setState within a render (which is what you are doing) as it will cause an infinite render loop (which I believe is the issue you are running into).

I would say pull the calculation out of the state. Put it on the this level and use it however you plan from there.

Comment: It *may* cause an infinite re-render. Still shouldn't do it, of course, but whether or not a state change causes a few-render depends on the state change and state comparison and/or shouldComponentUpdate (or whatever it is) logic. Just a minor wording nitpick :)